# How do I create a generator containing the top N values of another generator

Tags: python

I have an array of 132,000 normally distributed values, which is subjected to the generator `create_generator()`. This creates a generator representing an array of 132e+3 * (132e+3-1)/2 = 8.71e+9 rows and 3 columns. I want to extract the rows with the top N highest values of column 3. So 8.7 billion rows... I tried using `heapq.nlargest`, but this takes too long time since the generator is converted to a list. I am therefore wondering if there is a possibility of extracting the top N values without converting the generator to a list. Alternatively, is it possible to configure `create_generator()` so that  `g` is created in sorted manner on the fly?

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 132e+3)



def create_generator(x):
    p = x.shape[0]

    for i in range(p):
        for j in range(p):
            if i < j:
                yield i, j, np.mean( [x[i], x[j]] )



g = create_generator(x)


top10 = heapq.nlargest(100000, g, key=lambda x: x[2])
```

```
print(type(g))
<class 'generator'>
```

The top 10 values from `g` looks like this:

```
(84, 946, 3.050216283882091)
(39, 946, 3.0025937523565305)
(298, 946, 2.963771510516267)
(435, 946, 2.922654675946495)
(238, 946, 2.910720132624502)
(618, 946, 2.8948601555390985)
(39, 84, 2.8911608402386175)
(381, 946, 2.868888928662857)
(84, 298, 2.8523385983983536)
(84, 435, 2.8112217638285815)
```

```
print(type(top10))
<class 'list'>
```

I have tried with `heapq.nlargest()` to get the top N values (I want to top 100e+3 values), but this returns a list. I want to be able to create a new generator. How can I create another generator from a generator without creating a temporary list?

Comment: What about looping over the generated values and saving the N biggest in an array? (You can sort the arrray storing the biggest values to implement some smarter way to compare/replace with highest values)

Comment: Not sure I understand... but you cannot create a generator that returns the N largest values of another generator without running the second generator until the end every time... that is why the second generator is converted to a list.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia yes, you would have to run through the whole generator, but I think if you can do it at least memory-efficiently. But you are right, I don't think the speed would improve much.

Comment: `heapq.nlargest` returns a list, but what else would you want it to return anyway? In any case, it does visit every item, but it doesn't keep all the results in memory at the same time.

Comment: In order to yield the top `N` items (by order as it seems from your example), you need to first have those `N` items... In order to do that, you need to iterate the generator and save a list of size `N`... To avoid saving a list you will need to iterate the generator `N` times... Is that better for you?

Comment: Simple solution: `def my_nlargest(n, g, *, key): yield from heapq.nlargest(n, g, key=key)`. But of course this isn't automatically more efficient to have a generator instead of a list. This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) because what you really want is a more efficient solution, whereas you are asking how to implement a particular thing that you *think* will be more efficient but probably won't be.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to avoid the list creation with all your will, the only other option I can think of is the following conversion:

- Right now you have:

  ```
    One iteration => list of size N
  ```
- Instead do:

  ```
    N iterations => one variable
  ```

What the following does to avoid the list creation, is loop the generator `n` times. Each time grab the maximum element and save it. Each following iterations find the maximum ***excluding*** the previous ones:

```py
from math import inf

def top_n(n, x):
    global_max = inf
    for _ in range(n):
        cur_max = 0
        for i, j, elem in create_generator(x):
            if cur_max < elem < global_max :
                cur_max = elem

        yield cur_max
        global_max = cur_max
```

Note that this needs to get the ***iterable*** (`x`) and not the ***generator*** (`g`) to be able to loop from the start (doing `iter(generator)` returns the same object and not a copy).